# How do I link to a file in a different directory without using the whole address?

Tags: html, hyperlink, directory

I'm building a website on my computer's local server, with the plan to upload to my webhost with all the links and relative pathways intact. However, I've run into a problem with how to link to pages and images in directories higher up the hierarchy chain.

For example, let say my website is about food and all my logos and stylesheets are in the main .com directory. Then I add the subdirectory "fruit". Sure, I could keep all my Fruit images in the fruit directory, but how would I link back to my logo and stylesheet, and still have links that work when I upload everything to my webhost? When I would edit websites online, just plugging in the whole address was no problem (caused issues if I ever wanted to change the domain, but it would work), but building a website offline on my computer is causing some organizational issues.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the root directory using two dots like this:

../ and then your desired directory like logos or something assuming you are working inside a subdirectory as you mentioned "fruit".

Comment: Thank you, that helped me link to my logo and stylesheet with no problem. I've noticed another issue however and I'm not sure how this can be helped. I'm using PHP page includes to simplify future edits. When I tried to use the ../ with my .php pages, apparently some of the pathways in my PHP files (namely the images in my /images folder) don't work in the subdirectories I want to use them. I suspect in this case I would have to create new PHP files in the directories I'm working out of, right? So that all the relative pathways work in any given directory, right?

Comment: It's best to make a constant in your PHP script that contains the path to your root directory i.e define('ROOT_PATH', 'your path'); in a seperate file ex: config.php then you include it in each page so you can access the constants anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `../` to go up on level in a directory

```
 <a href="../your/path.html">Go Link</a>
```

If you want to go straight to the root directory. you have to start your URL with `/`

```
  <a href="/your/path.html">Go Link</a>
```

**PS:** Be aware that relative path inside CSS file will consider the `.css` file as starting point.

```
  body {
     /* Look for image.jpg in the same directory as css file */
     background-image: url('image.jpg');
  }

  div {
     /* Look for image.jpg one directory up in the hierarchy */
     background-image: url('../image.jpg');
  }
```

Comment: So, do you need to do a ../ for each directory you want to go up? like ../../ or ../../../ ? Is that how it works? Someone else said that ../ would take me to the root directory, but I think they may have been referring to me only having the 1 subdirectory I mentioned.

Comment: Perfect. As you said ../../ go up 2 directories. Starting with / go straight to root

Comment: I created a new subdirectory in my "fruit" subdirectory and answered my own question. Yes, each ../ will take you back (1) folder, so being 2 subdirectories in, I need 2 (../) to get back to the root directory.

Comment: I wish this page would update live . . . I hadn't realized you'd answered me when I posted. 

Now, I've been trying to figure out how to use the / to go straight to the root because then I could just code the PHP pages I want to include all over my website to be relative to the root directory regardless of wherever they actually are. But it's not working. In my new subdirectory ../../style.css will access the stylesheet in the root directory, but /style.css wont. If I could get this to work I could move forward with my website . . .

Comment: This website
http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php
says everything you just said about linking to the root directory, but my code simply isn't working. 

could this have anything to do with the fact that I'm working on my computer and / might be referencing a folder somewhere other than I want it to?

Comment: Be aware that '/' will not go to your root directory. It will go until the first / of your domain. for example: if i use `/index.php` in `http://yourserver.com/myapp/sub/index.php` it will look for index.pho in `http://yourserver.com/index.php` not "myapp/index.php". It will go up in the hierarchy until the highest top. Maybe that's your problem

Comment: That's actually what I thought you meant, but it still isn't working. I started a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889918/attempting-to-link-to-root-directory-on-home-computer where I show the address I'm working from. Maybe looking at the address will help clear things up? Also: isn't "yourserver.com" the root directory in this example? Because I thought that's what it meant. If not, what IS the root directory? =/