# Attempting to link to root directory on home computer

Tags: php, html, directory, root

I'm attempting to build a website on my computer and I'm having issues linking with my root directory from anywhere on the website. I know I can use `../` to go up 1 directory as many times as needed, but I need a way to link to my root directory without using the whole address so I can use "absolute links" to use in my PHP pages which I want to use all over my site for ease of editing. I've been told that `/` will take me back to the root, but it isn't working on my computer.

Here is the address for my deepest file (in my 3rd directory from the root)
http://localhost/_Website%20Files/cats/articles/_Blank-Cats2.php

The file I want is in **_Website Files** in the middle.But that's a folder INSIDE localhost, which I believe is being used as the root. There is a file within Localhost called `test.php` that I tried to link to to test whether LocalHost was being used as the root, but it didn't show up in _Blank-Cats2.php where I tried it. (does that make sense?) Somewhere in _Blank-Cats2.php there should have been a sentence that said "Php test for website", and it didn't show up.

Also, I'm using MAMP as my php localhost. If that helps anyone in anyway.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the problem with trying to link to a root directory on my computer?

**------Edit------**
I've changed my root directory to _Website Files, and now some of my /links are working, but others aren't.

For example, in my `Social-Media-Menu.php` file which I've included in my `_Blank-Cats2.php` page, using `/images/facebook.png` worked to locate the image. However, I cannot use `/Social-Media-Menu.php` to locate and include the php file, I have to use `../../Social-Media-Menu.php` or it won't work. Also, I was able to link to my style page with `/styles.css` from the save `_Blank-Cats2.php` page, but it wont work with my php pages. I was also able to make `/images/logo.gif` work.

So basically I can use `/` to link to my `/images` directory, but not anything IN the root directory itself. For that I need to use `../` or `../../` Maybe I'll just create a new directory just for php includes and see if that solves anything.

**------Edit-------**
So I created a new directory called `PHP-includes` and I put all the files I want included elsewhere in there. `header.php`, `menu.php`, etc. But when I went to use `/PHP-includes/header.php`, it didn't work.

However I HAVE noticed that the elements that ARE working are `html/css` based. My `/styles.css` is working, my `/images/logo.gif` is working. The only things NOT working are things I'm trying to include with PHP, so I think it has something to do with how PHP works. Could that be the case?

**-----Edit-------**
Aha! `/` will NOT work with PHP, I found that out here https://css-tricks.com/php-include-from-root/ So I guess I will need to mess around with my PHP code in order for it to behave and do what I want it to do. If you have any tips or tricks on how to do that (the example listed on that page I posted didn't makes sense to me) please feel free to post below =)

Comment: in your hdd where is the page? c://mamp/etc ?

Comment: I copied and pasted this address from my address bar, so I don't know why this wasn't included, as I know that's part of the address . . .

However I DID just find out how to change the root directory in MAMP, so now _Website Files is the directory, but it's weird. /image.jpg will work in a php file used in a 3rd level subdirectory, but /header.php wont work when I try to include it in the same directory. So i'm not sure what's going on there . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative paths will not work well with your PHP files. The solution I gave you here...

[How do I link to a file in a different directory without using the whole address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888675/how-do-i-link-to-a-file-in-a-different-directory-without-using-the-whole-address)

... was meant to work for client side resources only (HTML/CSS/Images). If you want to get the root directory in your PHP code you have to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`:

Then we would use something like this for all our includes:

```
  <?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/your/path.php"); ?>
```

You have to understand that some resources are loaded in server side (PHP Server) and what is loaded on client side (browser). That's why you can't do a generic solution working for both sides.

Comment: Ok, so I'm slowly starting to get this. If I understand this right, you're suggesting all my "php include" statements should be structured as you mentioned above, with the exception that "/your/path.php" would be replaced with the actual link relative to my actual document root, right? However, someone on my other pages said This --- It's best to make a constant in your PHP script that contains the path to your root directory i.e define('ROOT_PATH', 'your path'); in a seperate file ex: config.php then you include it in each page so you can access the constants anywhere --- Continued -

Comment: How would I go about declaring my ROOT-PATH, figuring out what my root is so I can actually set it, and then where would I include the file . . . I suspect in the [HEAD]. Also, I want to thank you for being so helpful. @nanndoj